# SQL Server 2008 Analytic Services.ADOMD Cannot connect to the database

Tags: sql-server, adomd.net

There is a strange error when I trying to connect SQL Server OLAP database via ADOMD.

Here is an error I get:

> Either the user, NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON, does not have access
>   to the jan database, or the database does not exist.

What can be the reason. I can run the same query via SQL Server Development Studio.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities here:

1. Logins in SSAS are done in one of two methods - either SSAS passes the windows identity of the thread making the request, or the login is anonymous. Note that if the windows identity of the thread making the request is a local machine account (such as ASPNET or ISUR), the server won't know anything about it and will treat it as an anonymous login. In this case, you'll need to add NT AUthority/ANONYMOUS LOGON to a role that can access your database.
2. If you've done this, there also seems to be some sort of bug when attempting to access a SSAS database anonymous on a Windows 2008 server related to the windows integrity mechanism. I've yet to find a good workaround, except for changing how connections work. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqldev/archive/2010/01/08/as-2005-as-2008-vista-win7-win2k8-sspi-anonymous-behaves-differently.aspx